# Моментальный вывод echo

Tags: php

Проблема собственно вот в чём.

Если в цикле вывожу на экран какие-то значения, то вывод происходит только после того, как
цикл завершил работу (сразу всё).

Как сделать так, чтобы строчки выводились каждый раз в виде появляющихся строк?

Comment: Вопрос из разряда - ajax без javascript или что-то в этом духе, долбите поиск, даже это можно сделать, но profit, мягко говоря, сомнителен. К тому-же, надо понимать, что - то, о чем вы пищите противоречит сути http протокола

Comment: Условно можно представить так: только когда скрипт отработает полностью данные выдаются в браузер.

Comment: Вообщем если вы решаете реальную задачу, а не тупо стало интересно - пишите что вы сделали, что читали, что думали, зачем вам это и т.д. и т.п., тогда мб и ответят

Comment: Может вам нужно просто вывести строки медленно по очереди, а не именно отдавать их по очереди?
Тогда можно отдать нормально всё, но на клиенте их получить JS'ом и вывести уже как нужно. Короче тут нужна ваша задача.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope), почему оно противоречит именно http?

[@Siter](/users/6008/siter), есть такая опция в `php.ini - implicit flush`, которая эквивалентна вызову функции `flush()` каждый раз после `print` или `echo`. Т.е. выбирайте тот вариант, который вам больше всего нравится или который вы можете у себя применить и применяйте. Правда, не стоит забывать, что это советуется делать только для отладки так как нагрузка будет серьезной на сервер.

Comment: http: запрос -> ответ -> вывод

Ну и смысл `flush` если это грузит сервер? Имхо страшный костыль

Comment: Спасибо большое. Именно то, что я искал)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, так все так и останется. Просто апач будет выдавать результат не по мере заполнения `output buffer`, а частями равными тому, что записано в `echo` или `print`. Это не противоречит ни самому http ни tcp, обладающему функционалом, благодаря флагу PSH.

Comment: Именно это - действительно не противоречит

Answer (score 3):

```
<?
while (ob_end_clean()){}; // на всякий случай
ob_implicit_flush(1);
echo str_repeat(chr(0), 4096); // IE
// погнали
$n = 5;
while ($n > 0) {
  echo 'text<br />';
  sleep(1);
  $n--;
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo str_repeat(chr(0), 4096); // ^.^`

Comment: Ну ИЕ дожидается первых 4096 байт до начала вывода, попадался я на эти грабли. И на первые попадался на бесплатном хостинге)

Comment: а вот это для чего?  
    
    while (ob_end_clean()){};

Comment: > И на первые попадался на бесплатном хостинге)

Это об нем) Если до начала скрипта включена буферизация - глушим ее.

Comment: Но зачем в цикле?

Comment: Мне это, где-то, напоминает IE6+ скрипт без библиотек ^.^

Comment: =/ Потому что она может быть включена в несколько уровней. Хостинг -> шаблон -> модуль, например.

Comment: Ну да, верно. С php.net про ob_end_clean
Возвращаемые значения  
Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. Основной причиной неудачного завершения работы функции является ее вызов без активной буферизации, или если буфер не может быть удален (специальный тип буфера).

Answer (score 1):

Вы также можете получить небуферизованный вывод в **Linux/Apache** без необходимости выполнять неявную очистку после каждой строки вызвав:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);

ob_end_flush();
```

...вначале скрипта.